# PHP allow memory size joining 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

I get an error allowed memory size exhausted. I found the query which was causing the problem.

I was joining 2 tables - orderdet and prodtexts

Orderdet contains details of orders 9k rows and prodtexts 500 rows.

When I run the query via sql I got result but with notice that there is no primary key set. When I updated the query to choose only columns I needed + containing 1 primary index column the result was ok. What can cause the problem ? Should I manually write queries containtnig columns I need? Now I am using `SELECT *`.

Comment: You do not provide enough details, but one thing that jumps to mind; are you sure the query was causing the exhausted memory issue or rather the work being performed on the results? Badly written JOINs can cause multiplication of results, some add php code to filter out the ridiculous results

Comment: Just thought of it resultscwere good nut each contained description of products - lot of html so i just selected the columns neccessery and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exceed memory limit, than it means in future you will face same issue if even if you increase memory limit.

*To change memory limit*

In *php.ini* file find `memory_limit` and change it to proper value (e.g. `memory_limit = 250G`).

Or from PHP script side: `ini_set('memory_limit', '250MG');`

---

Always optimize your queries. Take only what you need and try to reduce results size as much as possible.

Tips:

`SELECT id, name` instead of `SELECT *`

`SELECT [..] FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id` instead of `SELECT [..] FROM a, b` / `SELECT [..] FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id`.

`SELECT [..] FROM a, b` will (in your case) selects 9000 * 500 = 4500000 rows.

Don't forget to use `WHERE .. AND ..`, use `LIMIT` if possible.